# how to display a Mat in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

For the mat which stores images, it is easy to show it using `imshow`.But if the data type of the Mat is CV_32FC1, how can I display this mat ?

I tried imshow, but the display figure is totally white and when I zoom int, it is still totally blank, and I cannot see the float numbers in mat.

Is there anyone who knows how to show entire mat matrix ?

p.s.: thanks for replying. I will post some codes and figures to show more details: 
codes:

```
Mat mat1;
mat1 = Mat::ones(3,4,CV_32FC1);
mat1 = mat1 * 200;
imshow("test", mat1);
waitKey(0);

Mat dst;
normalize(mat1, dst, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);
imshow("test1", dst);
waitKey(0);

mat1.convertTo(dst, CV_8UC1);
imshow("test2", dst);
waitKey(0);

return 0;
```

output:

[image]

after I zoom in by 150%:

[image]

Then after I zoom in by 150%, we can see that 'test' is totally white and we cannot see its element values. 'test1' is totally black and we still cannot see its element values. But for 'test2', it is gray and we can see its element value which is 200.

Does this experiment mean that `imshow()`can only show `CV_8UC1` and we cannot show any other datatyes ?

Answer (score 24):

If `image` is a Mat of type CV_32F, If the image is 32-bit floating-point, [imshow()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) multiplies the pixel values  by 255 - that is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].
So your  floating point image has to have a range 0 .. 1.

This will display a CV32F image, no matter what the range is:

```
        cv::Mat dst
        cv::normalize(image, dst, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
        cv::imshow("test", dst);
        cv::waitKey(0);
```

Comment: Just wondering why the down-vote: this way works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm also wondering why the downvote. Normalize your float image in [0:1] and call imshow is perfectly valid. +1 for me